# Поиск файлов по расширению

Tags: c++

Интересует реализация поиска файлов по расширению. 
Например, я указал путь к рабочему столу и дальше при помощи функции я вывожу список всех `*.txt` документов, которые он нашел.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по упоминанию рабочего стола, вам под винду.
Тогда через `FindFirstFile("C:\\Some\\Folder\\*.txt", ...);` ну и `FindNextFile()` и `FindClose()`, конечно же.

Ссылка на пример в описании FindFirstFile на MSDN имеется

Comment: Ну, рабочий стол и в линуксе может быть.

Comment: @alexolut не во всяком, ой не во всяком...

Comment: Спасибо, вечером дойду до этого момента и попробую реализовать) п.с да, под виндоус) забыл упомянуть) буду знать на будущее

Comment: @goga там даже пробовать нечего, подход 100% рабочий.

Comment: ну, я делал уже что-то подобное но у меня было вручную все
ifstream Loading(s) и в s был путь к файлу (для считывания тхт по указанному пути) и с записью было так же